# Java Scanner doesn't work in Processing

Tags: java, processing, java.util.scanner

For an assignment I have due, my group and I were asked to code an educational/interactive game, and we decided on a basic maths one.

To get the users answers, we decided to use Java Scanner and put this line of code at the top of all the code we have;

`java.util.Scanner`

One of the loops that use this is the page with the questions on it, the loop looking something like this;

```
scoreCount = 0;

for (questions = 0; questions < 5;) {
  //get the user's answer
    userAnswer[questions] = input.nextInt();
  //text box for users answer

  if (userAnswer[questions] == compAnswer) { 
    //put tick next to answer

    //add one to score
      scoreCount = scoreCount + 1;
  } else if (userAnswer[questions] != compAnswer) {
    //put cross next to answer

  }

  //go to next question
  questions++ ;

}
```

I'm working through all the errors that were thrown up and every time i don't have `java.util.Scanner` commented out Processing throws us the errors `unexpected token:` and then either `class` or `void`, which i don't get, but when `java.util.Scanner` is commented out, the classes and voids all work and the `.input.nextInt()` isn't recognised.

I am new to Java programming and Processing, any help at all would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

i think this is the link which lets you see my code, it's called Test;

https://github.com/MeganSime/Week8DataVis

Comment: So you have `import java.util.Scanner;` at the top, right?

Comment: Show the Scanner code.

Comment: yeah i have `import` sorry, it just says unexpected token

Comment: sorry Masud, i don't understand what you mean Scanner code, a different member of my group coded the Scanner, i didn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to check if scanner has next int (token)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

.
.

if(input.hasNextInt()) { // or hasNext()
    userAnswer[questions] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably inserting a non `int` value where the scanner expects that. You should do something like that:

```
if(input.hasNextInt()) {
   userAnswer[questions] = input.nextInt();
} else {
   scan.next(); //consume any non-int value like ":"
}
```

Comment: i guess we can give a char even ?

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh [Scanner#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) expects an `int` and not a `char`.

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh No need to be sorry, this can confuse indeed. That's OK :)

Comment: does having the link to the full code change this answer at all? it look really good, other than do i need to change my if statement to that? i'm kinda confused :/

Comment: @MeganSime I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i meant the if statement i have in my question, if the one you gave me what i need to change mine to? i got it working, it's alright, though :) thanks anyway